# sklearn LedoitWolf covariance with missing

Tags: scikit-learn, missing-data, covariance

I am trying to estimate the shrunk covarance matrix with Ledoit and Wolf (2004) method for the dataframe test:

```py
from sklearn.covariance import LedoitWolf
LedoitWolf().fit(test).covariance_
```

I get the following error message:

```
ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64').
```

In fact, test looks like the following:

```py
array([[ 0.003675, -0.085502,  0.023041,  0.0112  , -0.0048  , -0.022344,
        -0.0048  , -0.1328  ,       nan, -0.152373,  0.061867],
       [ 0.038778,  0.187608,  0.065888,  0.137032, -0.0047  ,  0.081014,
        -0.215226,  0.018556,       nan,  0.179208,  0.047932],
       [ 0.0466  ,  0.012729,  0.128468,  0.162117,  0.020236,  0.138267,
         0.5966  ,  0.132964,       nan,  0.054852,  0.0216  ],
       [ 0.011873, -0.188127,  0.027068,  0.102509,  0.405091,  0.141985,
        -0.212333, -0.012   ,       nan,  0.241872, -0.05522 ],
       [ 0.02705 , -0.180671, -0.0042  , -0.014895,  0.382897, -0.080633,
        -0.109463, -0.126649,       nan,  0.099504,  0.164631],
       [-0.0037  , -0.122748, -0.022748, -0.068565, -0.131142, -0.101602,
         0.172771, -0.026956,       nan,  0.278179, -0.0037  ],
       [ 0.026003,  0.087592, -0.031484,  0.180671,       nan,  0.135235,
        -0.2043  , -0.061443,       nan,  0.17214 ,  0.004589],
       [ 0.010006, -0.1797  ,  0.035704,  0.083105, -0.166862,  0.008905,
        -0.0672  , -0.0047  ,       nan, -0.044968,  0.006411],
       [-0.1294  , -0.2544  , -0.00242 ,  0.005452, -0.0044  , -0.031986,
        -0.071067, -0.069265,       nan,  0.021406,  0.040657],
       [-0.030886, -0.1291  ,  0.0159  , -0.121173,       nan, -0.060838,
        -0.075529,  0.025312,       nan,  0.033636, -0.037433],
       [ 0.014349,  0.138857,  0.005804, -0.169746,       nan,  0.133405,
         0.149846,  0.024571, -0.026772, -0.023394,  0.110943],
       [-0.040036,  0.746   ,  0.182408,  0.04898 ,       nan,  0.103383,
         0.062667,  0.012667, -0.025277,  0.045689,  0.118887],
       [ 0.054652, -0.241695,  0.128631, -0.016179,       nan,  0.081248,
        -0.1286  , -0.031378,  0.039878,  0.114743,  0.005659],
       [-0.058546,  0.40275 , -0.061894, -0.016239,  0.030048, -0.105195,
         0.067929, -0.0035  , -0.0035  ,  0.033325, -0.06772 ],
       [ 0.132122,  0.049533, -0.038684, -0.081219, -0.0038  ,  0.008779,
         0.062867, -0.015229, -0.0038  , -0.034569,  0.00522 ]])
```

Is there a workaround to use `LedoitWolf` with missing data, other than imputing the missing with (say) median or mean values? Unfortunately, I am not allowed to make arbitrary assumptions about those missing data.

Comment: An idea is to bootstrap first, and then compute covariance on the bootstrapped samples. (depends on what exactly you're trying to achieve)

Comment: do you know if this approach is standard?